# Dropwizard/Hibernate: persisting objects with bidirectional one-many relationships gives error "NULL not allowed for column"

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, dropwizard

I'm using Dropwizard with Hibernate persistence. It's giving me a headache, because Hibernate appears to be "losing" objects' generated IDs before generating the SQL to persist my objects.

I have three classes: `Checklist`, `Checkpoint`, `ChecklistItem`, which I'm modelling as bidirectional one-to-many relationships.

I've built the domain objects, a DAO, a resource to expose it, and a bunch of tests (DAO tests, and an all-up integration test).

I notice some odd (broken) behaviour:

1. I can round-trip `Checklist` objects (and child objects) just fine within a transaction in my DAO unit test.
2. However, round-tripping via the Dropwizard REST resource fails.

Here's what I think I *ought* to be seeing in the logs (taken from good DAO test):

```
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Executing identity-insert immediately
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into Checklists (id, description, locked, name, ownerUserId) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[main] DEBUG o.h.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 1
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Executing identity-insert immediately
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into Checkpoints (id, name, checklistId) values (null, ?, ?)
[main] DEBUG o.h.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 1
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Executing identity-insert immediately
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into ChecklistItems (id, description, name, checkpointId, state, url) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[main] DEBUG o.h.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 1
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Executing identity-insert immediately
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into ChecklistItems (id, description, name, checkpointId, state, url) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[main] DEBUG o.h.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 2
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Executing identity-insert immediately
[main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into ChecklistItems (id, description, name, checkpointId, state, url) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[main] DEBUG o.h.id.IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 3
[main] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
```

Here's (the **bad**) I'm getting when I run my integration test:

```
127.0.0.1 - - "PUT /api/cl/v0.1/users HTTP/1.1" 201 - "-" "checklists-server (integration test client)" 240
DEBUG com.misys.uk.checklists.resources.ChecklistResource: Invoked ChecklistResource#createChecklist(uriInfo, newChecklist)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL: /* insert com.misys.uk.checklists.core.Checklist */ insert into Checklists (id, description, locked, name, ownerUserId) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL: /* insert com.misys.uk.checklists.core.Checkpoint */ insert into Checkpoints (id, name, checklistId) values (null, ?, ?)
WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 23502, SQLState: 23502
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: NULL not allowed for column "CHECKLISTID"; SQL statement:
/* insert com.misys.uk.checklists.core.Checkpoint */ insert into Checkpoints (id, name, checklistId) values (null, ?, ?) [23502-189]
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL: /* insert com.misys.uk.checklists.core.ChecklistItem */ insert into ChecklistItems (id, description, name, checkpointId, state, url) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
WARN org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 23502, SQLState: 23502
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: NULL not allowed for column "CHECKPOINTID"; SQL statement:
/* insert com.misys.uk.checklists.core.ChecklistItem */ insert into ChecklistItems (id, description, name, checkpointId, state, url) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-189]
ERROR io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 319c21e9a8198202
! org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "CHECKPOINTID"; SQL statement:
! /* insert com.misys.uk.checklists.core.ChecklistItem */ insert into ChecklistItems (id, description, name, checkpointId, state, url) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-189]
! at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.189.jar:1.4.189]
```

Here are my domain objects:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Checklists")
public class Checklist {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) @Column(unique = true)
    private long id = Constants.UNASSIGNED;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long ownerUserId;

    @NotEmpty @Length(max = 64) @Column(nullable = false, length = 64)
    private String name;

    @Length(max = 2000) @Column(length = 2000)
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean locked;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}) @OrderColumn(name = "cpOrderWithinCl")
    @JoinTable(name = "ChecklistToCheckpoint",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "checklistId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "checkpointId"))
    private List<Checkpoint> checkpoints;

    public Checklist() {
        // needed for Jackson
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public long getOwnerUserId() {
        return ownerUserId;
    }

    public void setOwnerUserId(final long ownerUserId) {
        this.ownerUserId = ownerUserId;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(final String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public List<Checkpoint> getCheckpoints() {
        return checkpoints;
    }

    public void setCheckpoints(final List<Checkpoint> checkpoints) {
        this.checkpoints = Preconditions.checkNotNull(checkpoints);
    }

    private void addCheckpoint(final Checkpoint newCheckpoint) {
        if (checkpoints == null) {
            checkpoints = new LinkedList<>();
        }

        newCheckpoint.setParent(this);
        checkpoints.add(Preconditions.checkNotNull(newCheckpoint));
    }

    private void removeCheckpoint(final Checkpoint checkpoint) {
        if (checkpoints != null) {
            checkpoints.remove(Preconditions.checkNotNull(checkpoint));
        }
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public boolean isLocked() {
        return locked;
    }

    public void setLocked(final boolean locked) {
        this.locked = locked;
    }

    // equals() and hashCode() ...
}
```

Entity `Checkpoint`, which has a one-many relationship to `ChecklistItem`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Checkpoints")
public class Checkpoint {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) @Column(unique = true)
    private long id = Constants.UNASSIGNED;

    @NotEmpty @Length(max = 64) @Column(nullable = false, length = 64)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn(name = "checklistId", nullable = false)
    private Checklist parent;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL) @OrderColumn(name = "ciOrderWithinCp")
    @JoinTable(name = "CheckpointToChecklistItem",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "checkpointId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "checklistItemId"))
    private List<ChecklistItem> items;

    public Checkpoint() {
        // Needed for Jackson
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Checklist getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(final Checklist parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public List<ChecklistItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(final List<ChecklistItem> items) {
        this.items = Preconditions.checkNotNull(items);
    }

    public void addItem(final ChecklistItem newItem) {
        if (items == null) {
            items = new LinkedList<>();
        }

        Preconditions.checkNotNull(newItem).setParent(this);
        items.add(newItem);
    }

    private void removeItem(final ChecklistItem item) {
        if (items != null) {
            items.remove(Preconditions.checkNotNull(item));
        }
    }

    // equals() and hashCode() ...
}
```

Entity `ChecklistItem`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ChecklistItems")
public class ChecklistItem {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) @Column(unique = true)
    private long id = Constants.UNASSIGNED;

    @NotEmpty @Length(max = 64) @Column(nullable = false, length = 64)
    private String name;

    @Length(max = 2000) @Column(length = 2000)
    private String description;

    @Length(max = 2000) @Column(length = 2000)
    private String url;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn(name = "checkpointId", nullable = false)
    private Checkpoint parent;

    @Column(nullable = false, length=16) @NotNull @StringEnumeration(enumClass = ChecklistItemState.class)
    private String state = ChecklistItemState.UNCHECKED.name();

    public ChecklistItem() {
        // needed for Jackson
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(final String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @JsonProperty @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(final String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Checkpoint getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(final Checkpoint parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public ChecklistItemState getState() {
        return ChecklistItemState.valueOf(state);
    }

    // equals() and hashCode() ...
}
```

I'm fairly certain it isn't DBMS related (I've tried several different ones, same problem occurs), and fairy sure it doesn't have anything to do with running under a transaction (I've peppered the code with debug `println()`s to confirm this).

I suspect this has something to do with the way I'm attempting to do the one-many mappings between my domain objects.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was quite simple: when persisting an object graph through Hibernate, where **bidirectional** relationships exist between entities, those relationships will be navigated by Hibernate in *both* directions.  If they are not correct, Hibernate will fail.

I didn't catch this initially, because I was constructing objects in my unit tests using a Builder, which itself was thoroughly tested -- I thought I had this covered. Obviously not!

The integration test was failing, because the bug lay with the JSON annotations (or lack thereof) to handle this bi-directional relationship -- and this was only being revealed in my all-up test, because only then was it exercising the broken JSON backreference behaviour!

- Use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` to properly annotate your objects to handle bidirectional references (child->parent, and parent->child).
- The above *won't* work if `@JsonIgnore` annotations are present on said fields.
- You *are* unit testing all this stuff, aren't you.... ?